# Python Unittests - How do I get rid of the testing?

Tags: python, pycharm

[image: Click here to see picture]

I'm writing a simple Python program but for some reason it's running weird tests instead of running the program itself. What do I do?
I am using Jetbrain's Pycharm...
The idea is to have a python program run a file of a made up language called Gvahinux that is similar to assembly just much much simpler...

So how do I get rid of the Unittests automatically being run?

**It's happening with any new program I open or write. What happened that pycharm is running tests on the program instead of simply running the program?**

Here's the code:

cpu = dict(REGS={
            'R0': 0,
            'R1': 0,
            'R2': 0,
            'R3': 0,
            'R4': 0,
            'R5': 0,
            'R6': 0,
            'R7': 0,
            'PC': 0,
            'CC': 0
        })

```
    def cpu_execute_line(line):
        parameter_1 = split_line(line)[1]
        parameter_2 = split_line(line)[2]
        command = commands[split_line(line)[0]]
        command(parameter_1, parameter_2)


    def mov(rx, op):
        try:
            if int(op):
                cpu['REGS'][rx] = int(op)
        except ValueError:
            cpu['REGS'][rx] = cpu['REGS'][op]
        cpu['REGS']['PC'] += 1


    def add(rx, op):
        try:
            if int(op):
                cpu['REGS'][rx] += int(op)
        except ValueError:
            cpu['REGS'][rx] += cpu['REGS'][op]
        cpu['REGS']['PC'] += 1


    def sub(rx, op):
        try:
            if int(op):
                cpu['REGS'][rx] -= int(op)
        except ValueError:
            cpu['REGS'][rx] -= cpu['REGS'][op]
        cpu['REGS']['PC'] += 1


    def mul(rx, op):
        try:
            if int(op):
                cpu['REGS'][rx] *= int(op)
        except ValueError:
            cpu['REGS'][rx] *= cpu['REGS'][op]
        cpu['REGS']['PC'] += 1


    def div(rx, op):
        try:
            if int(op):
                cpu['REGS'][rx] /= int(op)
        except ValueError:
            cpu['REGS'][rx] /= cpu['REGS'][op]
        cpu['REGS']['PC'] += 1


    def mod(rx, op):
        try:
            if int(op):
                cpu['REGS'][rx] %= int(op)
        except ValueError:
            cpu['REGS'][rx] %= cpu['REGS'][op]
        cpu['REGS']['PC'] += 1


    def comp(rx, op):
        try:
            if int(op):
                cpu['REGS']['CC'] = int(cpu['REGS'][rx]) - int(op)
        except ValueError:
            cpu['REGS']['CC'] = cpu['REGS'][rx] - cpu['REGS'][op]
        cpu['REGS']['PC'] += 1


    def test(cond):
        if cond == 'EQ':
            if cpu['REGS']['CC'] == 0:
                return True
        elif cond == 'NE':
            if cpu['REGS']['CC'] != 0:
                return True
        elif cond == 'HI':
            if cpu['REGS']['CC'] > 0:
                return True
        elif cond == 'LO':
            if cpu['REGS']['CC'] < 0:
                return True
        elif cond == 'HE':
            if cpu['REGS']['CC'] >= 0:
                return True
        elif cond == 'LE':
            if cpu['REGS']['CC'] <= 0:
                return True
        elif cond == 'AL':
            return True
        return False


    def jmp(cond, op):
        if test(cond):
            try:
                if int(op):
                    cpu['REGS']['PC'] = int(op)
            except ValueError:
                cpu['REGS']['PC'] = cpu['REGS'][op]
        else:
            cpu['REGS']['PC'] += 1


    def out(cond, op):
        if test(cond):
            try:
                if int(op):
                    print op
            except ValueError:
                print cpu['REGS'][op]
        cpu['REGS']['PC'] += 1


    def split_line(line):
        code_part = line.split("#")[0]  # in order to get rid of the comments'  MOV    R1   ,   0      #puts in reg
        if code_part.split():
            code_part = code_part.split()
            command = code_part.pop(0)
            code_part = "".join(code_part)
            code_part = code_part.split(',')
            return command, code_part[0], code_part[1]


    commands = {'MOV': mov,
                'ADD': add,
                'SUB': sub,
                'MUL': mul,
                'DIV': div,
                'MOD': mod,
                'CMP': comp,
                'JMP': jmp,
                'OUT': out
                }


    def execute_program(lines):
        while (cpu['REGS']['PC']) < lines.__len__():
            cpu_execute_line(lines[cpu['REGS']['PC']])


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        path = 'C:\Users\Banana\PycharmProjects\untitled1\\fib.gvahinux'
        program = open(path, "r")
        program = program.readlines()
        execute_program(program)
        print (cpu['REGS'])
```

Comment: Can you paste your simple python program code here for clarity

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.

Comment: What 'weird tests' are running?

Comment: "Weird tests" are the unit tests. I don't want them there and I don't know why it's running them...

Comment: @lxop The "weird tests" are the unit tests. I don't know what they are and I don't know why they are being run. I don't need them or want them...

Comment: How are you instructing PyCharm to run your code?

Comment: @lxop 
by right-clicking and pressing the run option

Comment: I simply want it to stop automatically running it through unittest and just run my program...

Comment: Just go to the left to the run button in the navigation bar and click edit configuration. There create a new configuration for your script and then hit the play button on the right side. If the script name is containing 'test' or is inside a folder called anything with 'test' in it, PyCharm interprets this as test file and the context menu option changes from 'Run xyz' to 'Run Unittests in xyz'

Comment: @Igle Thanks but I tried that already. I went to the configuration and put only the name of the file into it. In addition, it is not in any file with the word test. For some reason it did not work and when I ran it it automatically changed it back to it's previous state with the "Unittests" in it.